# Linq DataTable and Take Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, take

I have the following use of Linq from a datatable:

```
  var query = dt.AsEnumerable();
query = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(log => log.Field<byte>("Day") == day).Take(10);
```

The following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'` to
>   `'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>'`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have tried take(10) - Please can you advise?

Comment: Have you posted entire query without any modifications? The same query works for me fine (.NET 4). Are you filled in dataTable manually? if so please show code

Comment: Sorry no the var is declared as var query = dt.AsEnumerable(). If I explicitly declare it as IEnumerable<DataRow> how would I then get query.AsDataView() which is how I am binding it to a ListView?

Comment: Gotcha, modify the question please

Answer (score 4):

Does the error definitely point to that line, on its own? I'd expect you to get that if you tried:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable();
query = query.Where(log => log.Field<byte>("Day") == day).Take(10);
```

in which case you could fix it by changing the type of `query` to be explicitly `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

(If that's *not* the problem, please give us more context. A short but complete *method* demonstrating just the problem at hand would help.)

Comment: Sorry yes the var is declared as you have put it. If I explicitly declare it as IEnumerable<DataRow> how would I then get query.AsDataView() which is how I am binding it to a ListView?

Comment: @LukeWilkinson: You'd probably want to copy it back to a DataTable, e.g. with `CopyToDataTable` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx